# Reimbursed for moving expenses -- how does that work on taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, moving

I moved from AL to CA and my employer reimbursed me up to a certain amount and I paid taxes on the reimbursement amount as well from my paycheck. So wanted to know if that's something I can claim while filing 2023 taxes.

Comment: Unless your 'employer' is the US military and you moved on Permanent Change of Station orders, moving reimbursement for 2018 or later is taxable so withholding on it is correct. Your W-2 figures should include both the reimbursement and its withholding and you will use those inclusive W-2 figures on your return.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 this is an answer, not a comment

Comment: So for federal, I can't claim it as my employer is not US military. For state, if I am understanding correctly, it should be taken care of in the W2 I received, right? Is there anything I need to look at my W-2 to figure out if this has been addressed in my W2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your W2 should show all income that you have received from your employer including the reimbursement expenses (which are taxable income).

Your W2 will also show the total taxes withheld no matter how they were withheld (paycheck, reimbursement check, etc).

So all the relevant information is on the W2 and you can proceed with your tax return "normally".

> if that's something I can claim

What exactly do you want to claim here? You can potentially claim expenses that were not reimbursed, but if your employer covered your cost (including tax up), there is nothing to claim.

Disclaimer: in these cases its always best to talk to a tax adviser that looks at all your specific details.

Comment: TCJA also 'suspended' as of 2018 the deduction for unreimbursed moving expenses other than military-on-PCS, along with that for unreimbursed _employee_ expenses other than military reservists, 'qualified' (= low income) performing artists, some state/local officials, and disability-related. Nearly all the individual TCJA changes are scheduled to revert in 2026, but it remains to be seen if they actually do.